How to create a list of sub classes and get property of them in a usual loop
I have a simple class with Rank property. And several sub-classes that have the Salary property. Main class does not have Salary property.
I need to create a list containing only sub-classes.
Then I need to use loop to get and use Salary property of all list elements.
How I can do it?
There I described classes and sub-classes.
public class Worker
{
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    public Worker(int rank)
    {
        Rank = rank;
    }
}

public class Manager : Worker
{
    public Manager(int rank)
        : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 50000;
    public int Salary 
    {       
        get
        {
            return BaseSalary * Rank;
        }
    }
}

public class Marketer : Worker
{
    public Marketer(int rank)
        : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 20000;
    public int Salary
    {
        get
        {
            return BaseSalary * Rank;
        }
    }

}

And there I tried to make a list and loop for getting Salary property.
List<Worker> List = new List<Worker>();
var Manager = new Manager(3);
List.Add(Manager);
var Marketer = new Marketer(2);
List.Add(Marketer);

for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(List[0].Salary);
}

But I don't understand what syntax I need to use?
Can you help me, what should i change to make the code work?

Why can't the main Worker type have an abstract Salary property?  Are there Worker subtypes that don't have a Salary?

It can.
I just want to know if it possible to do that at all.
For example. Worker class is the old code and can't be changed at all.
And then i create 10 new sub-classes and give them a property which Worker do not have.
So the old code will work and new sub-classes will

If all workers have a salary, but the salary for each is calculated using a different algorithm, make Worker be abstract and create an abstract property for Salary on Worker.  Then override it on all subtypes:
public abstract class Worker
{
    public Worker(int rank) => this.Rank = rank;

    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public abstract decimal Salary { get; }
}

public class Manager : Worker
{
    public Manager(int rank) : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 50000;
    public override decimal Salary => BaseSalary * Rank;
}

public class Marketer : Worker
{
    public Marketer(int rank) : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 20000;
    public override decimal Salary => BaseSalary * Rank;
}

Or if only some types of worker have a salary while others do not, or Worker cannot be changed, create an interface for those that do:
public interface ISalariedWorker
{
    decimal Salary { get; }
}

public class Worker
{
    public Worker(int rank) => this.Rank = rank;

    public int Rank { get; set; }
}

public class Manager : Worker, ISalariedWorker
{
    public Manager(int rank) : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 50000;
    public decimal Salary => BaseSalary * Rank;
}

public class Marketer : Worker, ISalariedWorker
{
    public Marketer(int rank) : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 20000;
    public decimal Salary => BaseSalary * Rank;
}

Then modify your loop though workers to filter out those that do not have a salary by using Enumerable.OfType<TSalariedWorker>():
foreach (var worker in List.OfType<ISalariedWorker>())
{
    Console.WriteLine(worker.Salary);
}

Alternatively, create some abstract intermediate type SalariedWorker:
public class Worker
{
    public Worker(int rank) => this.Rank = rank;
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SalariedWorker : Worker
{
    public SalariedWorker(int rank) : base(rank) { }
    public abstract decimal Salary { get; }
}

public class Manager : SalariedWorker
{
    public Manager(int rank) : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 50000;
    public override decimal Salary => BaseSalary * Rank;
}

public class Marketer : SalariedWorker
{
    public Marketer(int rank) : base(rank) { }

    public static int BaseSalary = 20000;
    public override decimal Salary => BaseSalary * Rank;
}

Then change your list to be a List<SalariedWorker>():
var List = new List<SalariedWorker>();

Incidentally, you should probably make your static BaseSalary fields be readonly or const since changing them would cause your program to calculate salaries differently for all instances.

Thanks it is clear for me now.
Now I know that my original idea can't be cannot be implemented.
I do not know interfaces yet.
I knew i could use something similart to your solutions 1,3. But I thought there could be an easier way to do it.
Now i get it. There is no simpler way.
How can i close the topic and choose your answer is right answer?

List is a List<Worker>. This means it can contain elements that are Worker, or types that inherit Worker. I know your desire is to not have Worker elements in the list, but the compiler doesn't know that.
When you access each element, it's of type Worker. You can inspect the value to see if it's a different (child) type, and if it is, cast and use the child's members.
I'm going to change your loop to a foreach because that seems to make more sense in this case.
foreach (var worker in List)
{
    if (worker is Manager manager)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(manager.Salary);
    }

    if (worker is Marketer marketer)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(marketer.Salary);
    }
}


Is there a way to automatically get sub-class type?
Cause i want to make a lot of sub-classes (10+). And write this for each sub-class will lead to a lot of code lines.
